# Find/Replace special characters in text file using Bash script

Tags: scripts, text-processing, sed

I'm looking for some guidance on creating a script to find and replace special characters inside a text file.

I've come up with this piece of pseudo code but filling in the blanks is a bit harder:

- Find newline & replace by space.
- Find `CP` & replace by newline.
- Find `Mr. Mime` (with space) & replace by `Mr.Mime` (without space)
- Find tab & replace by space
- Find double space & replace by single space
- Find `%` & replace with nothing (aka just leave it out)
- Find " ATK DEF STA IV " & replace by space

"Find" stands for "Find All Instances".

I've been looking into `sed`, but I can't seem to find how I'd handle these special characters. Any ideas much appreciated.

EDIT: As asked hereby an little snippet of the input:

```
CP 1593
SSS
Sudowoodo♀
ATK     DEF     STA     IV
15  15  15  100.0%
counter
rock slide
CP 1262
SSS
Tangrowth♀4
ATK     DEF     STA     IV
15  15  15  100.0%
vine whip
grass knot
CP 1077
SSS
Mr. Mime♀
ATK     DEF     STA     IV
15  15  15  100.0%
confusion
psychic
```

And the expected output:

```
1593 SSS Sudowoodo♀ 15 15 15 100.0 counter rock slide
1262 SSS Tangrowth♀4 15 15 15 100.0 vine whip grass knot
1077 SSS Mr.Mime♀ 15 15 15 100.0 confusion psychic
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post some sample input and output.

Comment: What about longer sequences of spaces? should 3 spaces become 2? or 1? should CP be replaced even if it appears in the middle of a word, or only if it is surrounded by whitespace? or at a word boundary?

Comment: By experience I discovered there's no longer sequences than 2 spaces, but if there would be more there should be reduced to just one... CP should only be replaced if it has a space before & after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sed text process is strictly line oriented, so it's pretty difficult to replace newlines with sed.
Untested:

```bsh
cat file |
  tr '\n\t' '  ' |
  sed -e 's/ CP /\n/g' \
      -e 's/Mr[.] Mime/Mr.Mime/g' \
      -e 's/   */ /g' \
      -e 's/%//g'
```

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`.](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) Otherwise +1.

Comment: @zotteken: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (by click on the grey tick ✓ left to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.